# how to add image in this program instead of numbers like image slider

Tags: javascript

Untitled Document

```
<body>
    <form name="form2">
        <input type="text" id="p1" name="username" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="button1" id ="b1" value="Start" onClick="strt()">
        <input type="button" name="button2" id = "b2" value="Stop" onClick="stop()">
    </form>

</body>

<script>
    var a = 0;
    var intervalID;

    function test2() {

        document.getElementById("p1").value = a;
        a++;

    }

    function strt() {
        intervalID = setInterval("test2()", 1000);
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }

</script>
```

how to add image in this program instead of numbers like image slider..
    on start button image should be start and after every second image should be stop and on hover image also should be start and there should be next and prevous button i am a basic learner so if any one can help me ...

Comment: NO. Never "*and on hover image also should be start*". Why? Cause 100% of galleries actually PAUSE the slider on hover. It's called UX

Answer (score 0):

You should add an img-tag and change the source On update:

```
 <img id ='img1' src='src1.jpg'/>
```

The source of the img-tag can Be changed with javascript just the way you change the value of the inputelement. An array could be usefull to store all possible src-values

Comment: which image tag and how can i update an image to the other one and then how to control that with start and stop button

Comment: or can i create an array ?? and add image in every array element?? and then can i increase that array element???